# Excel Services Error in SharePoint 2013 - Unable to Open/Edit Excel Files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, error, configuration, excel-services

Every time I click on a excel file I am receiving a popup message mentioning -

> We're sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request

MS Word is working fine though.

I performed all the steps mentioned in the below given articles:

- [Configure Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219698.aspx)
- [Manage Excel Services trusted file locations (SharePoint Server 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219699.aspx)

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found the solution..** This is what I did -

Navigate to Document Library -> Library Settings -> Advanced Settings -> and changed the '*Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents*:' to '*Open in the client application*'.

and Excel sheets worked smooth :)!

I tried the same issue on another server without enabling the excel services and all the other saga (two links mentioned in my question) and it worked fine.

I was able to check-out and check-in an excel file without any fuss. Can someone confirm this please?

Comment: Hey Muhammedh, I was looking for answer to this also, works like a charm. Thank you for posting and sharing.

Comment: This solution is worked for me.
thanks for sharing this tips.
regards
Shiva

Comment: @shiva u are welcome bro :)!