# Excel Online on SharePoint/OneDrive - Error message: "We ran into a problem completing your request. Please try that again in a few minutes."

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, excel-online

I've got an Excel sheet saved on OneDrive for Business. Accessing it through a SharePoint web interface lets multiple users edit it at the same time.

It's worked great for a year, then last month we started getting this error intermittently when trying to update cells (data or formatting):

"Excel - We're sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request. Please try that again in a few minutes."

[image]

Sometimes the error appears for one user but another can do the exact same thing seconds later without trouble.

I've tried cutting down the quantity of data in the sheet and saving with a new file name and link, but neither solved the issue.

A search found a similar-sounding issue and the suggested fix was to restart the SharePoint server. Unfortunately I believe our OneDrive is hosted in the cloud, making that tricky:
[Excel Services we ran into a problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198973/excel-services-we-ran-into-a-problem)

This question is also similar to one asked nine years ago, but the problem is on a cell-by-cell basis rather than loading the whole sheet: [Excel Services Error in SharePoint 2013 - Unable to Open/Edit Excel Files](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66400/excel-services-error-in-sharepoint-2013-unable-to-open-edit-excel-files)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simplified the spreadsheet by splitting it in two and removing some unnecessary pages. That seems to have fixed the issue for now.